# PHP echo/mysql does not process special characters properly

Tags: php

I have a JSON file, accessed remotely from a third-party website. It contains strings with special characters such as these:

`"name":"StatTrak\u2122 FAMAS | Pulse",` and `"name":"\u2605 Butterfly Knife | Case Hardened",`

However, when I echo these values using the following PHP code:

```
$url = "https://www.example.com";

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);

$descriptions = $obj->rgDescriptions;
foreach ($descriptions as $key => $value) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($value->name);
    echo htmlspecialchars($value->name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

It prints these lines as:

`StatTrakâ„¢ FAMAS | Pulse` and `â˜… Butterfly Knife | Case Hardened`

**How can this be prevented?** This also occurs when storing these values in a MySQL table.

I have also tried the following:

```
$enc = mb_detect_encoding($value->name, "UTF-8,ISO-8859-1");

echo (iconv($enc, "UTF-8", $value->name) . ",");
```

But the results are the same.

Comment: Is your file format UTF-8 without BOM?

Comment: @entiendoNull This file is accessed remotely (from a third-party URL), so I do not know how to confirm this to you.

Comment: But, your file that is parsing it?

Comment: @entiendoNull Sublime Text tells me the file is a standart UTF-8 file.

Comment: I am not familiar with Sublime editor, but in Notepad++ there is under the format option some to choose in between. Countless of times changing regular UTF encoding to UTF-8 without BOM has saved me a lot of trouble. Maybe the standard format in Sublime is without BOM. Can't say.

Comment: @entiendoNull Unfortunately, Notepad++ already tells me the file is encoded in "UTF-8 (without BOM)". I also tried to change it to standart UTF-8, without success.

Comment: Standard UTF-8 is "without BOM". UTF-8 doesn't depend on byte order, so it doesn't have a byte order mark.

Comment: @melpomene I meant, in Notepad++, there is an option for "U8 without BOM", or just "UTF-8". Both of them are echoing the same thing. This is how I decode the JSON: http://pastebin.com/cfc04wmp

Comment: try decoding the string with `json_decode($jsonString)` and add a header `header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8')` before any output. What happens then? What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @entiendoNull This fixed the issue with echoing. Can you confirm this will fix it with a MySQL query on top of your head? I am not able to test it at this very moment, but will in the future.

Comment: I would assume that will fix the matter if your table has the appropriate encoding as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set `htmlspecialchars` encoding to UTF-8.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($value->name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: This does not work, unfortunately. It still echoes the unforgiving messed up characters.

Comment: Are you echoing in a html page with the right content type?
Can you try from CLI?

Comment: @Momo What is it then, if not HTML?